# Exercise on $\dim \ker T^i$, with $T^4=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a $4\times 4$ real matrix such that $T^4=0$.
Let $k_i =\dim \ker T^i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$.

Then, which of the following is **not** a possibility for the sequence $k_1,\ k_2,\ k_3,\ k_4$ ?

1. $k_1 = 3,\:\ k_2 = 4,\:\ k_3 = 4\:$ and $k_4 = 4$
2. $k_1 = 1,\:\ k_2 = 3,\:\ k_3 = 4\:$ and $k_4 = 4$
3. $k_1 = 2,\:\ k_2 = 4,\:\ k_3 = 4\:$ and $k_4 = 4$
4. $k_1 = 2,\:\ k_2 = 3,\:\ k_3 = 4\:$ and $k_4 = 4$

We have to find the nullity of  $T^i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$.

Nullity of $T^4$ is $4$ since $T^4=0$. Also  $T$ is nilpotent. Hence all the eigenvalues of  $T$ are $0$.Then is it possible to say anything about the nullity of $T$?

Comment: Think about Jordan form of $T$. There are only 4 possibilities, three of your options correspond to some Jordan form and fourth doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The matrix $T$ is nilpotent and so is similar to a matrix in Jordan canonical form. For sequence $(k_i)_{i=1}^4$, consider whether it is possible to construct matrix in Jordan canonical form implementing the sequence. For example, $k_1$ will tell you how many Jordan blocks should be in the matrix.