# Flag of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a $4\times 4$ real matrix such that $T^4=0$.
Let $k_i =\dim \ker T^i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$.

Then, which of the following is not a possibility for the sequence $k_1\leq\ k_2\leq\ k_3\leq\ k_4$ ?

1. $3\leq4\leq4\leq4$
2. $1\leq3\leq4\leq4$
3. $2\leq4\leq4\leq4$
4. $2\leq3\leq4\leq4$

well, it was asked previously but didn't receive an elaborate answer.

Comment: Can you link to where it was asked previously?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1578368/370778

Comment: What did you try?  Where did you get stuck?  Did you understand the answer's point about Jordan canonical form?

Comment: well, the answer is there.. Answer 1 corresponds to the Jordan matrix with only one block of size 4, Answer 3 comes from one with two Jordan blocks with size 2 each, and Answer 4 from one with size 1 and one with size 3. However, you can't get Answer 2 that way.

Comment: Nullity of $T$ will imply the number of jordan blocks related to $0$. That's all I could know. I din't quite get that answer. The question was actually asked in a national level test for entrance to Phd in India in $2015$ and the answer was given to be the second option

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose that $T$ is in Jordan canonical form (without loss of generality).  Note that for all $i$,
$$
\dim \ker T^i - \dim \ker T^{i-1}
$$
is the number of Jordan blocks *with size at least $i$* (here, $T^0$ is the identity matrix).