# What is not the possibility of dimension of the kernel $k_{i}$ (without using Jordan forms)

Tags: linear-algebra

This question was asked in linear algebra quiz and I was not alble to solve it and need helep.

> Question: Let T be a $4\times 4$ real matrix such that $T^{4}=0$. Let $k_{i}= \dim \ker T^{i} $ for $1\leq i \leq4$ . Which of the following is not a possibility for the sequence $k_{1} \leq k_{2} \leq k_{3}\leq k_{4}$?( Without using Jordan forms)

(i) $3\leq 4 \leq 4 \leq 4 $

(ii) $1\leq 3 \leq 4 \leq 4 $

(iii) $2\leq 4 \leq 4 \leq 4 $

(iv) $2\leq 3 \leq 4 \leq 4 $

I thought of using the fact that $\dim_{i} \geq \dim_{k}$ if $i <k$ and using it to contradict options but that doesn't contradict any of the options.

I don't have any other result in mind which I can use.

There are some solutions on this website like this:[Flag of subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260399/flag-of-subspaces). But all of them use Jordan forms but our instructor speciofically mentioned to not to use it.

Can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to construct simple examples for 1,3,4.

As for 2, you have: $\dim\ker\big(T\big) =1$ and $\dim\ker\big(T^2\big)=3$

Plugging this into an equivalent form of **Sylvester's Rank Inequality**:
$2 = \dim\ker\big(T\big) + \dim\ker\big(T\big)\geq \dim\ker\big(T^2\big) =3$
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The second option $1\le3\le4\le4$ is impossible.

Suppose $x$ is a basis for the one-dimensional $\ker T$.
Also, let $y,z$ extend $x$ to a basis for the $3$-dimensional $\ker T^2$.

Then $Ty\ne0$ but $T^2y=0$. So $Ty=\alpha x$; similarly $Tz=\beta x$.
Let $v:=\frac{1}{\alpha}y-\frac{1}{\beta}z\ne0$, so that $$Tv=\frac{1}{\alpha}Ty-\frac{1}{\beta}Tz=0$$ Thus $v=\gamma x$. But this implies $x,y,z$ are linearly dependent, a contradiction.